# How do I create a different customer account for each page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am very new to magento and I am creating a new site, but I want the login design to be different for each site on my website

Comment: what you want to create Please explain more???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your website is using multi website concept then create a separate theme for each website, then you can override the login page for each website and change it accordingly. If you have any issues, then provide full details.

Comment: If I have a two website, and I want each site to have a different design for the login.
How do I cancel the login page?

Comment: If you have two websites, then create a two separate theme in front end folder like this, **app/design/frontend/Package_Name/Theme1** and **app/design/frontend/Package_Name/Theme2**, after that overrride login page in both the theme that you have created and change its design.

Answer (score 0):

To change the login design for each website, you need to create a separate theme for each website and design it as per your need. Too many resources available for how to create a custom theme on Magento2? refer any of one. If you face any issues with creating theme, post a new question with full details.